# How to prevent download videos from online courses

Tags: wordpress, video-streaming

My client want to see his recorded video courses online. We are using WordPress CMS for the website. How i can prevent some one to download this video from website.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t prevent it if you want people to be able to watch it. The server does not know the difference between downloading and playing. The browser decides if the video ends up on disk, or on the screen.